# Storage keeps disappearing on my Android phone

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I have a Motorola Moto G with an Android OS and I've had this issue for a long while now. It's quite an old phone with 8GB storage but I don't really need a lot of storage for my needs right now, so that's fine. However, I've realised that the amount of storage I have keeps going down all the time when I haven't updated any applications or downloaded anything. This leads to me running out of storage constantly which is causing issues because it means I have to keep deleting applications which all used to fit on my phone fine.

I'm not asking for a solution, but I'd like possible explanations for what's happening with my storage and where it could all be going.

Comment: It's normal, 8 gb is too little even for few apps. Half of that is consumed by system a lot of Google apps and rest apps their cache data and media

Comment: Well it has worked for me for years and a while ago I had to start deleting apps. I know it's not a lot of storage but if it wasn't for this issue then it would work fine for my current needs. It's has worked fine in the past; its not a satisfactory answer to say "its normal"

Comment: I have the same problem with several Moto X phones.  Tech support suggests a factory reset, and that buys diminishing relief. As near as I can tell there is poor management of storage, and we get the result.  Mot tech support has only suggested different phones, and factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in Settings > Storage. It will show things like images, other files, cache. For example, I just had 2.5GB in Google Play Store cache!